# In a category, does the composition morphism need to exist?

Tags: category-theory

I revisited this [popular tutorial about category theory](https://bartoszmilewski.com/2014/11/04/category-the-essence-of-composition/) after some time and I realised that right at the beginning there is a statement about what a category is:

[image: Identities are omitted]

> In a category, if there is an arrow going from A to B and an arrow going from B to C then there must also be a direct arrow from A to C that is their composition.

Is that true in a standard category? All this time I was happy with my composition function

$$\circ : \operatorname{Hom}_\mathcal{C}(A,B)\times\operatorname{Hom}_\mathcal{C}(B,C)\to\operatorname{Hom}_\mathcal{C}(A,C)$$

To my knowledge this function never complained when the codomain was the empty set. Was I operating in something that is not a category? Or is the statement in the tutorial an oversimplification and I'm being too pedantic?

Comment: +1 just by the picture. Very funny :D

Comment: I don't take any credit @Dog_69 it's from the page in the link

Comment: OK. But still... It's worth.

Comment: Maybe you were operating in $\mathsf{Rel}$-enriched categories without knowing ($\mathsf{Rel}$ is the category of sets and relations between them) ?

Comment: No smartpants :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the codomain is the empty set and the domain is not, then the composition map cannot exist as there is no map from a non empty set into the empty set. Hence the existence of such a composition map rules out this situation.

Comment: In other words, if $Hom(A,C)$ is empty the composition function proves that one of $Hom(A,B)$ or $Hom(B,C)$ must be empty

Comment: Thanks, sometimes my brain doesn't go that extra step.

Comment: @Chessanator This holds for all functions, not just composition; there is no function from a non-empty set to the empty set. Put another way, the set of all functions from non-empty sets to the empty set is the empty set.